# os.walk and os.scandir are returning ~$ in place of the 1st and 2nd characters of a file name

Tags: python, os.walk, scandir

I have a python script that is reading all the filenames and paths in a directory on a share drive. It then takes those path names and file names and builds some HTML hyperlinks I can add to our website so I do not have to do these manually one by one. The script works as expected but for some reason both `os.walk` and `os.scandir()` are returning `~$` on some of the path and file names replacing the 1st and 2nd characters in the file name.

I am unable to locate any documentation on this behavior so if anyone has some insight that would be great.

The code I am using looks like this:

```
import os

f = os.scandir(path=r"\\server_path\share_folder")

print(f)
for fn in f:
    format_name = fn.name.split('.')[0].replace('_', ' ')
    print(r'        <p><a href="{}">{}</a></p>'.format(fn.path, format_name), "\n")
```

Comment: http://www.diedesignsoftware.com/support/knowledge-base/whats-that-squiggly-mark-in-front-of-my-filenames

Comment: It's not being added by Python, it's really in the filename.

Comment: BTW, that article was the first hit when I googled "Windows tilde filename"

Comment: @Barmar thanks for the link that makes sense as we have hundreds of people who have access to that drive. I am guessing if i simple exclude filenames that start with `~$` I can avoid this problem.

Comment: I am not sure you can consider this question as off topic. There is a programmatic way to solving this problem. Now that I know what the problem actually is I can simple exclude any file names that start with `~$` with an if statement and move on. Seeing that there is a programmatic way of resolving this issue I think it would be inaccurate to close this as off topic.

Comment: There's nothing in the question about excluding filenames. The question asks why Python is replacing characters, and the answer is that it isn't.

Comment: @Barmar the question was from a point of not knowing what was going on. However with knowing then the answer to solve the problem is to exclude the temp files. There are many situations where the problem lies outside of the code but there is a way to work around the issue with code.

Comment: Please update the question to say what you really want. How to exclude them doesn't really depend on where they come from, you do that with a simple `if fn.name.startswith('~$')`

Comment: @Barmar I am not sure what you mean by "What I really want". I wanted to know why my code was returning filenames and paths with `~$` in them and you provided a link that answered that question. Knowing the answer does not change the original question. I know how to exclude the filenames I already fixed my code for that after you provided the link explaining what was actually going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the [link](http://www.diedesignsoftware.com/support/knowledge-base/whats-that-squiggly-mark-in-front-of-my-filenames) @Barmar provided in the comments I learned that the file names with `~$` at the beginning is actually a temp file that is there when someone else has the file open. With this knowledge I can now fix the issue by simply excluding the files with that prefix.

Code:

```
import os

f = os.scandir(path=r"\\server_path\share_folder")

print(f)
for fn in f:
    if fn.name[:2] != "~$":
        format_name = fn.name.split('.')[0].replace('_', ' ')
        print(r'        <p><a href="{}">{}</a></p>'.format(fn.path, format_name), "\n")
```